# How to set proxy authentication for Android sdkmanager from command line?

Tags: android, authentication, proxy, android-sdk-manager

I want to pass proxy authentication (username and password) along with proxyhost and proxyport

currently Android sdkmanager supports --proxy_host and  --proxy_port (in command line)

our proxy server has authentication also (username and password)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can export proxy environment variable, then run sdkmanager command

```
export http_proxy=http://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[PROXY_ADDRESS]:[PROXY_PORT]
```

For https proxy

```
export https_proxy=https://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[PROXY_ADDRESS]:[PROXY_PORT]
```

If the above command does not work, try

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=[PROXY_ADDRESS] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[PROXY_PORT] -Dhttp.proxyUser=[USERNAME] -Dhttp.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]" bash -c "sdkmanager '[SDK_COMPONENT]'"
```

This is because command **sdkmanager** will run as a normal java application. It will apply the options you specified in the command line.

Comment: how to add proxy authentication to android sdk manager for vs 2017?

Comment: how to do it on Windows?

Answer (score -2):

One thing I suggest you do is this.

Goto

> Settings->Appearance and Behaviour->System settings-> HTTP Proxy

[image]

Change the settings there. Hope this helps.

Also, you could try the following code from the command line.

```
sdkmanager --list --verbose --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=<proxy_host> --proxy_port=<proxy_port>
```

Comment: I want to pass the authentication from command line not from the studio

Comment: I also need to set the authentication. @SHASHIDHARMANCHUKONDA can you did it?